# Google In-App Review - Android native Not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, google-play, google-reviews

I am currently working on a requirement to display a In-App review  popup within the app for user reviews. Unfortunately, I am encountering difficulties in getting the In-App Review popup window to appear. I I have followed the guidelines provided in the following link

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java

To provide more context, I am including the code snippet below that I have utilized:

```
private fun requestInAppReview() {
    val reviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
    val request = reviewManager.requestReviewFlow()

    request.addOnCompleteListener { requestInfo ->
        if (requestInfo.isSuccessful) {
            // The flow will be launched if the request is successful.
            val reviewInfo = requestInfo.result
            val flow = reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo)

            flow.addOnCompleteListener { _ ->
                // The review flow has finished.
                // You can log or perform actions after the review is completed.
            }
        } else {
            // There was a problem requesting the review flow.
            // You can log or handle the error accordingly.
        }
    }
}
```

I am using following dependency.

```
implementation("com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1")
implementation("com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.1")
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide to help resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you should consider while integrating and testing InAppReview on the app.

Best way to test it is throgh either internal app sharing or internal testing as it does not have any quota.

You can also use `FakeReviewManager` class of the framework.

Also thre are few known issue and solution mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test#troubleshooting). Please consider them while testing.

Hope it helps